How can I compile a c program to a baremetal rv32i processor?
Im developing a c++ risc-v simulator which emulates the rv32i ISA. I have the toolchains installed and generates files correctly.
I executed this command:
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc testing_program.c -march=rv32i

And to read the disassembly:
riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump -d a.out > program.dump

The thing is that, the disassembly file appears to only have rv32i instructions (which is correct), but when i use the a.out on my simulator, which has a disassembly, the disassembly throws many unrecogniced instructions.
The program is so simple:
int main(){
    int a = 1;
    a = 1 + 2;
}

No libraries nor includes, just that, just for testing.
I'm not going to put the disassembly file because is too long, but it looks like this:
a.out:     formato del fichero elf32-littleriscv


Desensamblado de la sección .text:

00010094 <exit>:
   10094:   ff010113            addi    sp,sp,-16
   10098:   00000593            li  a1,0
   1009c:   00812423            sw  s0,8(sp)
   100a0:   00112623            sw  ra,12(sp)
   100a4:   00050413            mv  s0,a0
   100a8:   289000ef            jal 10b30 <__call_exitprocs>
   100ac:   d481a783            lw  a5,-696(gp) # 12558 <__stdio_exit_handler>
   100b0:   00078463            beqz    a5,100b8 <exit+0x24>
   100b4:   000780e7            jalr    a5
   100b8:   00040513            mv  a0,s0
   100bc:   595010ef            jal 11e50 <_exit>

000100c0 <register_fini>:
   100c0:   00000793            li  a5,0
   100c4:   00078863            beqz    a5,100d4 <register_fini+0x14>
   100c8:   00012537            lui a0,0x12
   100cc:   d1850513            addi    a0,a0,-744 # 11d18 <__libc_fini_array>
   100d0:   3950006f            j   10c64 <atexit>
   100d4:   00008067            ret

000100d8 <_start>:
   100d8:   00002197            auipc   gp,0x2
   100dc:   73818193            addi    gp,gp,1848 # 12810 <__global_pointer$>
   100e0:   d4818513            addi    a0,gp,-696 # 12558 <__stdio_exit_handler>
   100e4:   07018613            addi    a2,gp,112 # 12880 <__BSS_END__>
   100e8:   40a60633            sub a2,a2,a0
   100ec:   00000593            li  a1,0


You need to use the compiler & linker options for bare metal.  You're getting the standard C library stuff instead.

@ErikEidt Ok thanks, just to know some theory, as I'm pretty new to all this stuff, my disassembly now looks pretty short with just the main label, but i'm not getting exacly what is my compiled file content. why does my disassembly tells what instructions contains, but my in my binary file there are no instructions like my disassembled file says?

As "riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump" tells you, the file "a.out" is an ELF file. This format includes more than just the binary machine code, and this is what you see in your simulator.
Note: "a.out" is the historic default name of the linked executable. You might want to use a real name with the -o option when building.
Use "riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy" to extract only the machine code, like this (untested, since I don't have that tool chain installed):
riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy -O binary a.out a.bin

Please consult its documentation for more details.
